# Object reference

Tags: java, object

I have a problem to get to right object. When I start my program it creates a object. And when I call opon a methode, the methode creates a new object, but when I am trying to print the object information, I am getting information from the first object. How do I refere to the new object ?

```
public Meny () {
    tekstgr = new Tekstgrensesnitt();
    fil = new Fil();
    this.cde = new CDarkiv();
}

public CDArkivADT lesFraFil(CDArkivADT cde, String filnavn) throws java.io.IOException {

       try {  
       // // 1 - FileReader
       FileReader ansFil = new FileReader(filnavn);

       // 2 - BufferedReader
       BufferedReader innfil = new BufferedReader(ansFil);

       // 3 - Leser den første posten som er antall info-poster
       String linje = innfil.readLine();
       int n = Integer.parseInt(linje);

       // Oppretter CDarkiv
       cde = new CDarkiv(n);

       // 4 - Les postene, en hel post om gangen
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String post = innfil.readLine();
            String[] felt = post.split(SKILLE);
            int nr = Integer.parseInt(felt[0]);
            String artist = felt[1];
            String tittel = felt[2];
            int år = Integer.parseInt(felt[3]);
            Sjanger sjanger = Sjanger.valueOf(felt[4]); //Eventuelt lagret som heltall
                                                        //...Må så konvertere til enum

            String plselskap = felt[5];

            CD cd = new CD(nr, artist, tittel, år, sjanger, plselskap);

            cde.leggTilCd(cd);    


       }
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cde.getArkiv()));
       // 4 - Lukk filen
       innfil.close();

      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException unntak) {//arver fra IOException må stå først
                                            // hvis ikke vil unntaket for IOException skygge
       System.out.println("Finner ikke filen " + filnavn);
       System.exit(-1);
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("Feil ved lesing av fil: " + e);
       System.exit(1);
      }

      return cde;
     }


public void start() {
    Scanner tast = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filnav = "test.txt";
    System.out.println("Press '1' for å 'Lese fra fil'" + "\n" + "Press '2' for å 'Skrive til fil'");
    int g = tast.nextInt();
    if(g == 1) {
        try {
            fil.lesFraFil(cde, filnav);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 

    System.out.println("Tast '1' for å søke etter tittel." + "\n" + "Tast '2' for å søke etter artist/gruppe");
    int f = tast.nextInt();
    if(f == 1) {
        String twmp = tast.nextLine();
        String temp = tast.nextLine();

        CD d = cde.finnCD(temp);

        tekstgr.visCD(d);
    } else {
        String temp = tast.nextLine();
        cde.finnArtist(temp);
    }

}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Meny meny = new Meny();
    meny.start();

}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, your description of the problem is extremely vague. I only see one method that returns an object: `lesFraFil`. I only see one call to that method `fil.lesFraFil(cde, filnav);` where you don't do anything with the returned object.

Comment: What object are you talking about?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this is an extremely lazily-asked question. You give no indication (well, ok, a very vague indication) of what the actual problem is, and you expect us to sift through dozens of lines of code to find it. Put a little more work into your question, please. You should work *at least* as hard in the asking as you expect us to put in in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, sry, my bad...

Comment: So I have made a CD archiv. In the end, it should be avaiable to do different kind of stuff, like read data from a list and get a CD archiv from that list, write a CD archiv. kind of create a CD archiv etc... At this point the problem is to read the file, "test.exe". In the start() methode, at the point CD d = cde.finnCD(temp); I get a NullPointException...

Comment: And what I think cause this problem is because it is refering to the wrong CD archive since the program creates a archiv when the main methode is calling the Meny method...

Answer (score 0):

Where is your first declaration of `cde`?
When you pass it through your method, the reference you get in your parameters is a copy of the original reference, thus assigning a value to it does not change the original variable.

I see you are returning `cde` in your method, and this works, but you are not using the returned object in your main method. I'd suggest remove the `cde` parameter as it is pointless, and change your `lesFraFil` call like this:

```
CDArkivADT cde = file.lesFraFil(filnav);
```

Comment: Is your `lesFraFil` method inside `Meny` object? If so, why are you passing `cde` as parameter if it already has this property?
Doing so, the `cde` you're assiging in you method is the one passed from parameters. If you wish to assign a value to your instance `cde`, use `this.cde`. Than again, there's no point in passing `cde` as a parameter...

Comment: Neverming, your `lesFraFil` method is from `Fil` class.
Just remove the parameter from the method and use the return value.

Answer (score 0):

public class CDarkiv implements CDArkivADT {

```
private CD[] cdTabell;
private int antall;

public CDarkiv (int antall) {
    this.antall = antall;
    cdTabell = new CD[antall];
}

public CDarkiv() {
    antall = 0;
    cdTabell = new CD[0];
}

{...}
```

public interface CDArkivADT {

```
public void utvidKapasitet();              //Utvider kapasiteten til et CD arkiv
public CD[] getArkiv();                    //Henter arkiv
public void leggTilCd (CD c);              //Legger til en CD i arkiv
public void slettCd (CD c);                //Sletter en CD i arkiv
public CD finnCD (String s);               //Finner CD-er ved gitt delstreng
public String finnArtist (String s);       //Finner alle CD-er som tilhører en artist ved gitt delstring
public int hentAntall(Sjanger sjanger);    //Henter antall CD-er i en sjanger
public int getAntall ();                   //Henter antall CD-er
```

}